# Link ParseObject to Facebook user

Tags: android, facebook, parse-platform

I want to link a Parseobject, let's call it movies to a facebook user.
I'm trying to follow the tutorial about Relations : https://parse.com/docs/relations_guide#onetomany-pointers

There is no sign of an example server side.
What i'm doing right now is :

```
ParseObject movie = new ParseObject("Movies");
movie.put("createdBy", ParseUser.getCurrentUser());
```

But in my table "Movies" in what type should i create my "createdBy" column ? Is it Pointer ? And if it is, toward what i should target it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you to create a column 'createdBy' as a Relation. Once you have created this column in the data browser, you could use the following code(from the Parse docs):

```
ParseObject movie = new ParseObject("Movies");
ParseRelation<ParseObject> relation = movie.getRelation("createdBy");
relation.add(ParseUser.getCurrentUser());
movie.saveInBackground();
```

This should create a Relation in the 'createdBy' column in the data browser.